# How do I make a slack bot leave a channel?

Tags: bots, slack

Bots cannot use the regular `channels.leave` API call, so how do I make a bot leave a channel, short of kicking it? I need it to leave a channel where I do not have rights to kick users.

Answer (score 69):

You can `/remove` (or `/kick`) the bot.
Type `/kick @botname` in the channel which you want the bot to leave.

Comment: for public channels, only team owners and admins can use the remove action. All other get `Removing from channels is a restricted action`

Comment: FYI, I'm guessing you cannot remove @slackbot from a channel. The command `/kick @slackbot` does not work, because it says @slackbot is not a member of the channel.

Comment: It isn't possible: *@slackbot* is not a member of this private channel.

Comment: The question specifically said they don't have the rights to kick users, so this answer isn't exactly that helpful... except to Googlers who do have those rights, I suppose!

Comment: We made a Slack integration that handles this very problem (It auto deletes all Slackbot responses as it can't be kicked): https://github.com/UnitedIncome/slackbot-destroyer

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking about Slackbot in particular, you cannot remove it from a channel (see [Slack's response](https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/813799142833192960?lang=en) to this question).

If you have permission to delete Slackbot's responses, you can install [this bot](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/slackbot-destroyer), which will delete Slackbot's automated responses for you.