# Can I disable Slackbot without kicking it from channel

Tags: bots, slack

I am frustrated with Slackbot's app suggestions. The most irritating part is that it keeps suggesting me apps even though it knows (it suppose to know) that I cannot install them. And each time I click "Yes", I am smashed with not-enough-privileges error.

I cannot [kick it off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38233034/1469208) because:

- I don't have proper privileges for public channels,
- I think it is impossible to kick it off / stop it from talking in private chats / direct messages.

Can I somehow disable these suggestions without kicking it off? Can I somehow have Slack without Slackbot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, not. That's the reason people have gone ahead to create things like [Slackbot-destroyer](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/slackbot-destroyer).

You can put a curtain on some noise, though. In Slack preferences, go to `Advanced` and uncheck the boxes next to `Send me occasional channel suggestions via Slackbot` and `Send me occasional surveys via Slackbot`. I don't think these are enough, though. They should have an option to turn it entirely off.

From a recent twitter [conversation](https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/1309636176563843073).